# Sluggish render VueJS page with 2000-3000 items

Tags: vue.js, lodash, vue-component, vuejs2

I have an administrator view which can display a list of users. Complete list is about 3000 entries. I have pagination enabled by default to 100 users/page, but the admin has the option to display all of them at once.
When 100 users are displayed, everything is fine, but when all 3k are displayed the page becomes sluggish (e.g. if i try to sort a column, it'll take 3-4 seconds to sort them) and I understand there's not much I can do about the response time. I'm using `lodash OrderBy` method for sorting.

**My question is**, is there a way to have VueJS rendering the list asynchronously, so if I click sort by Name, then immediately sort by Level, it will cancel the existing sorting operation and start a new one?

Here's a sample code (it doesn't work obviously, i just made it up to illustrate my point):

```HTML
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3" @click="setSort('name')">
                Name
            </div>
            <div class="col-3" @click="setSort('level')">
                Level
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" v-for="u in sortedUsers">
            <div class="col-3">
                {{u.name}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                {{u.level}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            users: []
            ,orderCol:'name'
            ,orderDir:'asc'
        })
        ,computed : {
            sortedUsers () {
                return _.orderBy(this.users,this.orderCol,this.orderDir);
            }
        }
        ,methods : {
            setSort(col){
                this.orderCol = col;
                this.orderDir = (this.orderDir=='asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
            }
        }
        ,mounted () {
            this.$post('/getusers')
            .then((data) => {//assume data is in this format:
                // [{'name':'test1', 'level':'admin'}, {'name':'test2','level':'user'}, and so on]
                this.users = data; 
            });
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You can do quite some things to improve performance.. For starters, use a key attribute on the looped elements. Also, this lib might make it significantly faster: https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. There is no way to render all 3000 items async.
Ordering is fast, rendering is slow. Even though you can speed up ordering by laravel or any other app it will not help you to render quicker. You can't speed up rendering by async as I know.

Some links:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/441

- Try to use short list with for example 100 items + pagination (local, just offset for `v-for`).
- [`vue-virtual-scroller`](https://akryum.github.io/vue-virtual-scroller/) is also interesting if your list of items has fixed height. ([Demo](https://akryum.github.io/vue-virtual-scroller/))

Comment: 1. I know about pagination and speed, please read my entire post again. 2. Someone else already mentioned virtual scroller in the comments